# Blackberry Development - Create a received SMS

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sms, inbox

I want to develop a Blackberry application which creates a received SMS in the SMS inbox. Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK you can add received email and PIN message in inbox but not SMS.